# How do people of Southern hemisphere refer to seasons?

Tags: terminology

I wonder whether they call "winter" the December, January and February or the opposite, the June, July and August?

Comment: This is off-topic. Go ask on [English.SE].

Comment: @curiousdannii I am not asking about English, I am asking about all languages.

Comment: Then [edit] your question to make it on-topic!

Answer (score 2):

In the Southern hemisphere moderate climate zone the colder season is also called 'winter', but the winter months are June, July and August, since all the countries that use the Gregorian calendar have the same month at a given time.

Comment: Is this in all southern hemisphere countries?

Comment: @Anixx - Not in all the southern hemisphere countries English and the English word 'winter' is used. And in the countries closer to the equator the seasons are not 4, but 3 or 2.

Comment: I know, so my question was about different languages, that is say, Spanish and Portuguese.

Comment: @Anixx - Why didn't you write that in your question? And you, probably, want to know the names of the seasons in every country of the southern hemisphere, don't you?

Comment: only for those who use Northern-hemisphere derived language with a word meaning "winter" in Northern hemisphere.

Comment: And in the tropics of both hemispheres the seasons are completely different.